# Transition with partial opacity

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm following the guide here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html to animate a popup and their overlay. I need the overlay with a final opacity of 0.5 but Vue set it to 1 at the end. I tried something like this, but Vue animate the opacity to 0.5 and abruptly change it to 1 at the end of the animation:

```css
.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
.fade-enter-to {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Here is a test that illustrate the problem https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/58865/

**Update**

Working solution https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/58877/ There is no need to add the final opacity to the fade classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also set the opacity on the `.overlay` class (this is what will be used after the transition has finished):

```
.overlay {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/58867/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but doesn't work initially. Probably any other mistake in my trial an error process.